# How to maven jar-with-dependencies pom.xml overwriting

Tags: java, maven, project, pom.xml

I have a `pom.xml` which should generate a `jar-with-dependencies` and include all external and all written classes into my jar file and it should be executable (with `MainClass` definition). Now my project gets it own `pom.xml` from a remote repository via `<parent/>`. I override the `maven-assembly-plugin`, but everytime I call `jar:jar`, I get my jar only containing my own class files, not the external classes. If I run `assembly:single`, I get all external class files, but not my own classes.

The parent pom.xml look like this:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <organization>
        <name>123</name>
        <url>123.com</url>
    </organization>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>build</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>Cp1252</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <compile.java.version>1.6</compile.java.version>
    </properties>


    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>dsc-repository</id>
            <name>buildmaster-releases</name>
            <url>${repository.releases}</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>dsc-repository</id>
            <name>buildmaster-snapshots</name>
            <url>${repository.snapshots}</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${compile.java.version}</source>
                    <target>${compile.java.version}</target>

                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>

                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Title>${project.artifactId}</Title>
                            <Version>${project.version}</Version>
                            <Vendor>${project.organization.name}</Vendor>

                            <Build-Timestamp>${env.BUILD_ID}</Build-Timestamp>
                            <Build-Number>${env.BUILD_NUMBER}</Build-Number>
                            <Build-Revision>${env.SVN_REVISION}</Build-Revision>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- disable java doc on release -->
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have no chance to change this pom.xml!

The following pom.xml overrides (throught the  element) the settings (I think) and is executed:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>DSCTest2Certificate</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.dscsag</groupId>
        <artifactId>build</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <compile.java.version>1.7</compile.java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- <plugin> <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId> <version>2.4</version> 
                <configuration> <archive> <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor> 
                <manifest> <mainClass>com.dscsag.dsct2c.main.MainClass</mainClass> </manifest> 
                <manifestEntries> <splashscreen-image>com/dscsag/dsct2c/resources/icons/loader/splash_screen.png</splashscreen-image> 
                </manifestEntries> </archive> </configuration> </plugin> -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.dscsag.dsct2c.main.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <splashscreen-image>com/dscsag/dsct2c/resources/icons/loader/splash_screen.png</splashscreen-image>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.swinglabs.swingx</groupId>
            <artifactId>swingx-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.toedter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcalendar</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jgoodies</groupId>
            <artifactId>jgoodies-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jgoodies</groupId>
            <artifactId>jgoodies-looks</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dsct2c.help</groupId>
            <artifactId>jreleaseinfo</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dsct2c.help</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdf_render</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dsct2c.help</groupId>
            <artifactId>jh</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dsct2c.help</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsviewer</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dsct2c.help</groupId>
            <artifactId>dsct2c_help</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <scm>
        <url>http://svnserver/svn_devel/plm/trunk/modules/DSCTest2Certificate</url>
        <connection>scm:svn:http://svnserver/svn_devel/plm/trunk/modules/DSCTest2Certificate</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://svnserver/svn_devel/plm/trunk/modules/DSCTest2Certificate</developerConnection>
    </scm>

</project>
```

How to solve my problem???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `mvn jar:jar` or `mvn assembly:single` you are not running the maven life-cycle which means the configuration parts will not run as you expect them to run.

You have to call:

```
mvn package
```

instead which will the maven-jar-plugin as well as the maven-assembly-plugin as you have defined it in your pom.xml file.

Comment: Thank you! I searched for this answer now for 10 h :)

Answer (score 0):

I also had a hard time to find this answer. 
And I found this comment in here. I hope it helps.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html

Note: Configurations inside the < executions> tag differ from those that are outside < executions> in that they cannot be used from a direct command line invocation. Instead they are only applied when the lifecycle phase they are bound to are invoked. Alternatively, if you move a configuration section outside of the executions section, it will apply globally to all invocations of the plugin.